# How do I fix my dough after I did not activate the yeast properly?

Tags: baking, bread, yeast, pastry

This is my first time making anything using yeast, but I decided to try making Dominique Ansel's At-Home Cronut recipe. Everything was going fine, but I realized that I had bought rapid-rise yeast instead of instant yeast. I tried subbing the rapid-rise anyways, using the same amount that was designated for the instant yeast. I added warm water and other liquid ingredients in order to activate the yeast, but instead of putting it in a warm moist place to rise I simply left it on my kitchen counter at room temperature. Now the dough has been sitting in my refrigerator since last night. I'd like to finish this tonight, but the dough didn't really rise for reasons that are now obvious to me. What is the best approach for salvaging this situation? I really don't want to start over since I need these cronuts for tomorrow, but I'm willing to go buy more yeast if I have to.

Would appreciate a reply on this ASAP so I can get moving on finishing this.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: It never hurts to add more yeast. I would recommend buying some new yeast though, as it is pretty common for packet yeast to go bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it in the fridge probably didn't help matters any. If you had left it on the counter overnight it would probably have gotten its act in gear without further help. Yeast works slower when cool than when warm, but it does work, given time.

IMPE, dry packet yeast going bad is somewhere between rare and unheard of - unless it's stored somewhere that is too hot, or the "warm liquid" is over 115F, and that's not going bad, that's killing the yeast. Stored in the fridge, it lives effectively forever, certainly years past the expiration date.

If you have some yeast left, or buy a new packet, rehydrate it in a little water (a tablespoon/15ml or so is plenty) at about 100 degrees F (38C), give it 5-15 minutes of undisturbed soaking time, and mix into the dough - add a little flour if needed to compensate for the additional liquid.

Comment: And the liquid should bubble after those 5-15 minutes ...if it doesn't, don't mix it in with the dough.  And you'll then need to let the dough rise for a couple of hours until it's doubled.  (it might be as short as an hour if the dough is already warm ... but if it's still in the fridge, it'll be a while before it's warm & working)